# Intermediate Modular Arithmetic Strategy And Questions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have these problems and I know how to solve ones with two equations but not more.  Can anyone provide solutions?  Thanks in advance!

---

Find the smallest positive integer that satisfies the system of congruences
\begin{align*}
N &\equiv 1 \pmod{7}, \\
N &\equiv 7 \pmod{13}, \\
N &\equiv 13 \pmod{20}.
\end{align*}

---

Find the smallest positive $N$ such that
\begin{align*}
N &\equiv 6 \pmod{12}, \\
N &\equiv 6 \pmod{18}, \\
N &\equiv 6 \pmod{24}, \\
N &\equiv 6 \pmod{30}, \\
N &\equiv 6 \pmod{60}.
\end{align*}

---

How many positive integers less than or equal to $6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9$ solve the system of congruences
\begin{align*}
m &\equiv 5 \pmod{6}, \\
m &\equiv 4 \pmod{7}, \\
m &\equiv 3 \pmod{8}, \\
m &\equiv 3 \pmod{9}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Nobody will provide you with solutions, but will be glad to offer assistance if you tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Do you know about the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: However, for the second problem, the answer's probably $\textrm{lcm}(12, 18, 24, 30, 60) + 6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem 1:

$$N=7p+1$$
$$7p+1 \equiv 7 \pmod{13}$$
$$7p \equiv 6 \pmod{13}$$
$$p \equiv 12 \pmod{13}$$

(This is calculated by finding the inverse of 7 mod 13).

$$N \equiv 7*12+1 \pmod{13*7}$$

$$N \equiv 85 \pmod{91}$$

$$N = 91q + 85$$

$$N \equiv 13 \pmod{20} $$

$$91q + 85 \equiv 13 \pmod{20} $$

$$91q \equiv 8 \pmod{20} $$

$$11q \equiv 8 \pmod{20}$$

$$q \equiv 8 \pmod{20} $$

$$N \equiv 91*8+85 \pmod{91*20}$$

$$N \equiv 813 mod \pmod{1820}$$

$$N = 813$$

For problem 2, $N = 6$ is the obvious solution.

For problem 3, we see that it is not possible to have $N \equiv 5 \pmod{6}$ and $N \equiv 3 \pmod{9}$ (first suggests $N$ is not divisible by 3, second suggests $N$ is divisible by 3). So, here there are 0 valid solutions.